# Can Winsock LSP on a router modify forwarded packets?

Tags: winsock, packet-mangling

If a Windows machine acts like a router (gateway) for others, will Winsock LSP filters that are installed on it be able to capture/mangle traffic of those machines?

If no, which technologies are there for this?